# Can two hydrogen atoms with parallel electron spins form a covalent bond?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, bond, theoretical-chemistry

Is it possible for two hydrogen atoms with parallel electron spins (i.e. a pair of spin-up electrons, or a pair of spin-down electrons)
to form a covalent bond? I've seen some say there is no sigma bond formation in that situation due to the Pauli exclusion principle, whereas others say one of the two electrons undergoes a spin flip, with bond formation occurring naturally after that.

I would expect 50% of collisions in a gas of free hydrogen atoms to have up spins, and 50% to have down spins. So, on average, any given pair of hydrogen atoms are equally likely to either have parallel or antiparallel spins. Does this imply that only 50% of H–H collisions in that situation result in a bond, i.e. would this impact the yield of the reaction?

How would this look with other elements?

Comment: The mixed answers you get are actually describing the same picture. Initially there is no sigma bond in that situation, and then there occurs a spin flip.

Comment: @IvanNeretin After the flip has passed, however, a sigma orbital is created. Where does the energy for the flip come from? Shouldn't it come from the fact that some is released by the bond?

Comment: The flip does not need any energy.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So one electron reorients itself by the magnetic field of the other before the sigma bond happens so that both then have an antiparallel spin and can then transition into the sigma orbital?

Comment: When you say "parallel" and "antiparallel", what do you mean? As in, parallel to what? Normally when people use these words it's in the context of an external magnetic field being applied, is this the case here? If not, then you may want to just use "up" and "down" spin (and in this case, the spin states are *degenerate*, so indeed no energy is required to go from up to down spin or vice versa). Only when you have an external magnetic field do spin flips require energy (and even then, only in one direction; the reverse flip releases energy).

Comment: @orthocresol By parallel I mean: Up-Up or Down-Down, by antiparallel I mean: Up-Down or Down-Up from each electron spin of the hydrogen atom.

Comment: Aha, I get you. 50% parallel and 50% antiparallel is a bit awkward, though; technically, yes, if you pick any two hydrogen atoms you will get parallel spins 50% of the time and antiparallel 50% of the time. But it's probably clearer to say 50% up and 50% down.

Comment: @orthocresol But I wonder now, why does it need energy when you have an external magnetic field? For example, would the spin of electron in hydrogen change if I hold a bar magnet near hydrogen?

Comment: @jemeto7849 You just rediscovered [Magnetization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization).

Comment: My guess is that the parallel and antiparallel spin states for an H2 would be indistinguishable when the H atoms are infinite distance from each other, so it's a bit like Schrodinger's cat(?) because you can't say for sure which spin which H atom has. Only when the H atoms come close to each other and start interacting, the two spin states would have different energies and would be distinguishable. I don't know the answer to your specific question though.

Comment: In the absence of any magnetic field or other distinguishing system, I would expect all of the atoms to exist as a superposition of "up" and "down" such that it is meaningless to discuss a difference between them. The formation of the bond results in a stable state that has net zero spin, but even in that state it is not possible to assign up or down spin specifically to either electron

Answer (score 3):

I'll specifically answer this part of your question:

> I would expect 50% of collisions in a gas of free hydrogen atoms to have up spins, and 50% to have down spins. So, on average, any given pair of hydrogen atoms are equally likely to either have parallel or antiparallel spins. Does this imply that only 50% of H–H collisions in that situation result in a bond, i.e. would this impact the yield of the reaction?

**TL;DR: No, only 25% of collisions will be able to result in a bond.**

In general, when you "measure" something in quantum mechanics, you force the system into the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions to some operator. In your case, you are looking at the electron spins, and once you measure them, your overall system is collapsed into an eigenstate of the spin operator. For a hydrogen molecule with its two electrons, those eigenstates are a singlet state $\alpha \beta - \beta \alpha$, and a triplet state with three "microstates" $\alpha \alpha$, $\beta \beta$ and $\alpha \beta + \beta \alpha$.

In the non-interacting case, we assume that each spin result ($\alpha$ or $\beta$) is measured with 50% probability on each of the free atoms.<sup>1</sup> Then, for any pair of atoms, we measure each binary spin combination $\alpha \alpha$, $\alpha \beta$, $\beta \alpha$ and $\beta \beta$ with the same 25% probability. If those atom pairs now draw closer together and start to interact, then the $\alpha \beta$ and $\beta \alpha$ combinations must combine to form either the triplet or singlet microstates with equal probability; in other words, isolated atoms with opposite spins have equal chances of forming a singlet or a triplet state when they interact. However, the $\alpha \alpha$ and $\beta \beta$ combinations are also still possible, and since they belong to the triplet state, the latter still wins over the competing singlet state with a 3:1 ratio. And since we know that only the singlet state leads to formation of a bond, we expect 25% of atom collisions to be able to form a hydrogen molecule.

**NOTE**: As @Paul pointed out in the comments, the explanation here is solely regarding the probabilities of bond formation that come from the spin statistics. There are further effects from collision cross-sections and energy dissipation that I am not taking into account here. In reality, less than the 25% of atom-atom collisions stated above would actually result in the formation of a bonded molecule.

---

You may wonder: "If we measure eigenstates to the spin operator, how can the isolated atoms yield the specific spins combinations $\alpha \beta$ and $\beta \alpha$? The spin operator is still the same, so why wouldn't we expect to see the singlet and triplet states again? What happened to them?"

At this point, it's vital to remember one important rule: **Any linear combination of eigenfunctions to the same eigenvalue is again an eigenfunction.** <sup>2</sup> When two atoms are non-interacting, measuring the singlet or triplet microstates of $\alpha \beta \pm \beta \alpha$ is still perfectly possible; but the same is true for their linear combinations that form the "distinct" $\alpha \beta$ and $\beta \alpha$ states.<sup>3</sup> What you measure now depends on what answer you seek, and each set of answers is as valid as the other. (But again, this is *only* true if there is no energy difference between the triplet and singlet states.)

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Note that I'm treating this as the *premise* of your question. If your ensemble of atoms does not conform to this assumption, e.g., due to the presence of external fields, then the answer will also be different.

<sup>2</sup> This is very easy to show. Assume $\hat{O} \Psi_1 = E_1 \Psi_1$ and $\hat{O} \Psi_2 = E_2 \Psi_2$, with $E_1 \ne E_2$. Then, $\hat{O} (a\Psi_1 + b\Psi_2) \ne (E_1 + E_2) (a\Psi_1 + b\Psi_2)$. However, if $E_1 = E_2 = E$, then $\hat{O} (a\Psi_1 + b\Psi_2) = E (a\Psi_1 + b\Psi_2)$.

<sup>3</sup> Let $\alpha \beta + \beta \alpha = \Psi_1$ and $\alpha \beta - \beta \alpha = \Psi_2$, then $\frac{1}{2} (\Psi_1 + \Psi_2) = \alpha \beta$ and $\frac{1}{2} (\Psi_1 - \Psi_2) = \beta \alpha$.

Comment: your analysis is only based on spin statistics and ignores reaction cross sections. In addition, it is good to note that a collision between two atoms in the gas phase can only produce a bound molecule if it dissipates the bonding energy by release of a photon or by collision with a third body. Since radiative transitions in molecular hydrogen are dipole forbidden, three-body collisions are required to form molecules.

Comment: True. I'll add a disclaimer.

Comment: This is a good answer to the core question (whereas I've only challenged the premise), but I object to the statement "In the non-interacting case, we assume that 50% of our free hydrogen atoms have α and 50% β spin." If you haven't measured them, the correct statement is "we assume a 50% probability of measuring $\alpha$ and 50% probability of measureing $\beta$ spin."

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I'll incorporate that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the premise of your question is flawed, which isn't your fault. It's the way students are introduced to quantum mechanics at the intro level. But if you could somehow generate a gas phase of free hydrogen atoms, it isn't correct to say that 50% would have "up" electron spin and 50% "down." What is correct is that *if you measured the individual spins* you would get 50% up and 50% down.

What's the difference? That's the weirdness of quantum mechanical systems. Individual electrons do not have defined spin until you measure it. Prior to that, they exist in a superposition of both possible spin states with a 50% chance of each result *if you take a measurement.*

So in your hypothetical, when two hydrogen atoms interact, there are no different cases to consider. Every pair of hydrogen atoms are the same. You have two electrons of undefined spin. When the atoms bond, the electrons become entangled so that the now diatomic system has net zero spin, but still neither electron has defined up or down spin. Only the net spin is defined.

If this doesn't make much sense, you're not alone. Quantum mechanics in many ways does not make sense. All we can say is that the empirical description we've come up so far does a very good job of predicting experimental outcomes. *Why* that description works is utterly unknown.

Comment: "when two hydrogen atoms interact, there are no different cases to consider. Every pair of hydrogen atoms are the same" - This seems wrong to me. If we measure their spins, we must get an eigenvalue to the total spin operator, and those eigenvalues will correspond to overall triplet or singlet states with their corresponding 3:1 weights.

Comment: @Antimon - Yes, *if we measure their spins*, they must collapse to a state represented by an eigenvalue. But prior to measurement, they have no defined spin. So if you somehow picked out a pair of atoms and measured their spins, you could create a pairing of up/up or down/down. But in a bulk mixture that hasn't been measured, all atoms are the same.

Comment: I'm still missing a connection between the bulk state of isolated atoms and the formation of a bond. I'll address this in an answer of my own, see if you can comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- if one or both electrons are in an excited state and they thereby occupy different orbitals. Of course, the excited state electron(s) would decay rapidly, so either the atoms blow apart from the resulting energy release or an electron spin-flips to preserve/strengthen the bond.